# Drupal email is empty. What is wrong with my attachment?

Tags: php, email, drupal-7, attachment

I can't find what's wrong with the attachment. The email is sent empty.
This is for drupal 7 customized webform. Here is my code:

```
<?php 

module_load_include('inc', 'print_pdf', 'print_pdf.pages');
$file_content = module_invoke('print_pdf', 'generate_path', '/****.pdf');

$attachment = array(
'filecontent' => $file_content,
'filename' => '****.pdf',
'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
'list' => TRUE
);

$message = array(
'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'),
'key' => 'test',
'to' => '****@****.com', 
'from' => '****@****.com',
'attachments' => $attachments,
'subject' => 'Test email',
'body' => 'test'
);

$system = drupal_mail_system('mimemail', 'test');
$system->format($message);
$result = $system->mail($message);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check path and access to file.

I use this code to send unmanaged files as attachments with Mimemail and MailSystem:

```
/**
 * Send email with attachment
 */
mymodule_send('default', array(
      'params' => array(
        'subject' => 'Mail suject',
        'body' => '<p>Mail body</p>',
        'attachments' => array(
          array(
            'filename' => 'HumanreadableFileName.xls',
            'filemime' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', // xls mime
            'filepath' => 'public://2016-04-18_report.xls',  // path to file
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ), 'john@doe.com');

/**
 * Implements hook_send().
 */
function mymodule_send($key, $params = array(), $to = NULL, $from = NULL) {

  if (!valid_email_address($to)) {
    $to = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));
  }

  drupal_mail('snabmail', $key, $to, language_default(), $params, $from);
}
```